# In gnss3, why can't I ping my cisco router from my VM?

Tags: cisco, routing, subnet, networking, gns3

I have the following network, I have never configured a Cisco router before so I'm having a little trouble. In router R1 I used the following commands to assign an ip to the router:

```
configure terminal
interface fastEthernet 1/0
ip address 192.168.1.1 255.255.255.0
no shutdown
```

For R2:

```
configure terminal
interface fastEthernet 0/0
ip address 192.168.1.2 255.255.255.0
no shutdown

configure terminal
interface fastEthernet 2/0
ip address 192.168.3.1 255.255.255.0
no shutdown
```

Now for the VM servidor-1 I assigned the IP 192.168.3.5/24 with 192.168.3.1 as the gateway. However I can't ping neither router, R1 and R2, from the VM. In the Mikrotik router all I had to do was assign the IPs in the router and it worked.

[image]

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 0):

R1 and R3 require a route back to 192.168.3.0/24 via R2. Without it, they use their default route towards the Internet for the echo reply. Without a default route, there's no route at all and the packet can only be dropped.

You need to either add the route statically or configure a routing protocol like OSPF.

Comment: But shouldn't I be able to atleast ping R2 from the VM?

Comment: Then you haven't connected the VM correctly. If you can ping from the host it's a virtualization issue, otherwise it's an issue with the host. Note that either is off-topic here.

Comment: can you ping 192.168.3.1 from VM? if yes then configure routing in R1, R2 and R3. I